# PHP cURL Post request not working

Tags: php, curl

I having issues running the correct cURL request. I am meant to do a Post request to the URL.

The example only runs a command line cURL request

```
$ curl -i -X POST {URL}
```

The issue I am running the following code and I am getting '400 Bad Request'

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

Can anyone help with sending the request correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` you wanna get by the request.
As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code) you're gonna need to set those fields:

```
<?php
//
// A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

?>
```

Comment: I did not include `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` as I did  ot have any fields to send. Once i added the line it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> POST Function:

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
  $postData = '';
   //create name value pairs seperated by &
   foreach($params as $k => $v) 
   { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
   }
   rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}
```

> Calling the Function:

```
$params = array(
   "name" => "Ravishanker Kusuma",
   "age" => "32",
   "location" => "India"
);

echo httpPost("http://hayageek.com/examples/php/curl-examples/post.php",$params);
```

See, if that helps. Ref: [link](http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/#curl-post)

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array );
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 0):

To post, just make use of following curl options and try.

```
(if your url is - "https") {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); //if required.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
return curl_exec($ch);
```

I guess the url you are passing doesn't have post fields. eiter you can make use of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and your post params their or else attache it to the url using http_build_query(post params)
http://www.url.com?arg1=val1&arg2=val2

Answer (score 0):

Also after spending 5 hours at same code i just found the solution of my problem

If you are using Array in post Fields you have to json_encode that array to recognize as POST parameters

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       $data = curl_exec($curl);
```

So This is Working CURL Code WITH POST Request
Give a Rep+ If my